# When analyzing a difference for log-transformed data, when to take the log?

Tags: data-transformation, logarithm

I am working with laboratory data that needs to be transformed due to skewness.  It has been gathered at 2 time points and I am interested in the change from time #1 to Time #2.  My question is, do I log transform the original values, then subtract the difference in the log-transformed data?  Or do I calculate the difference from the raw values then log transform the difference?  (That presents a problem in itself, since the difference can be negative, so could not be logged).

Comment: Just as a note: taking the difference of two log-transformed variables is equivalent of taking the log of their ratio: $\log_a(\frac{X}{Y}) = \log_a(X) - \log_a(Y)$. If you then back-transform the difference that you've taken with the log-data, you get the ratio $\exp(\log_a(X) - \log_a(Y)) = \exp(\log_a(\frac{X}{Y})) = X/Y$.

Comment: +1. You've answered your own question. A difference between logarithms is perfectly meaningful. A logarithm of differences is not. Depending on what kind of lab you frequent, think of pH. It is a logarithm, and people do work with differences on the pH scale.

Comment: "*I am working with laboratory data that needs to be transformed due to skewness.*" -- why does skewness pose a problem?